# Horizontal menu bar with horizontal sub menu does not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I use the following HTML program for creating Horizontal menu bar with horizontal sub menu.It was working fine in Fire Fox and Chrome **but it doesn't work in IE**.So **What are the changes are need changes in this program?**

```
<html>    
<head>          
<style>       
    /* Targeting both first and second level menus */

#nav li {
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {

    background-color:red;
    color:#FFF;
    opacity:1;
}

/* Targeting the first level menu */
#nav {  
    top:150px;
    min-width:850px;
    background:#fff;
    opacity:0.5;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
}
#nav > li > a {
}

/* Targeting the second level menu */
#nav li ul {
    color: #333;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    width:850px;
}
#nav li ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 8px 0 10px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
    background-color:red;
    color:#FFF;
    opacity:1;
}

/* Third level menu */
#nav li ul li ul{
    top: 0;
}
ul.child {
background-color:#FFF;  
}
/* A class of current will be added via jQuery */
#nav li.current > a {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    float:left;
}
/* CSS fallback */
#nav li:hover > ul.child {
    left:0;
    top:34px;
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
}
#nav li:hover > ul.grandchild  {
    display:block;
}       

</style>        
</head>       
<body>

 <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Hard Drives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Speakers</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">10 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">20 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">30 watt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Equipment</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Repairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Installations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Setups</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>         
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In future, please consider including a jsfiddle - here it is http://jsfiddle.net/DAMr5/

Comment: Please be aware that your navigation will be a nightmare to use in a mobile browser...

Comment: @Jace this fiddle also not working in IE

Comment: I didn't fix anything for you. I was asking you to consider sharing a JSFiddle when you have questions in the future.

Comment: What exactly does not work in IE( also which version of IE) I have IE9 its working fine in that one.

Comment: What version of IE?  It works fine for me in IE9.  The fiddle screen itself is not working for me at all in IE8 for some reason...

Comment: @MarmiK I use IE8 .In this version the above code not working

Comment: @Freethinker Am using Ie8

Answer (score 0):

do you use modernizr? or have available classes for legacy IE browsers? You might want to try messing with separate styles and/or stylesheets for IE.

Or

You can switch your navigation from floated blocks to "inline" elements, which older browsers such as IE6 that don't work well with floats will recognize.

Or

If you want to stick with floats then make sure you are setting a "width" for any floated element.

Chris Coyier has a nice article on floats that contains a section labeled: "Problems with Floats" 
http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

Well for some reason I can't even get the fiddle site to work at all in IE8...?  But one problem I noticed in your CSS, is opacity.  IE8 doesn't support the opacity property.  To change the opaqueness of elements in old IE, use `filter:alpha(opacity=75);` Note, the value 75 is a whole number from 1 to 100, not a decimal like with the opacity property.  I wish I could be more help, but I can't even see what the problem is in the fiddle...